# how do you specify a timeout for an Intern test that returns a promise

Tags: timeout, promise, intern

In Intern I can specify a timeout using this.async(), for example

```
var d = this.async(1000);
xhr(..., d.callback(...));
return d;
```

However, how can I specify a timeout if my test returns a Promise?  For example:

```
return asyncFunc().then(function(res){
    assert.strictEquals(res, 2);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `this.timeout` to your timeout value. See [Writing Tests with Intern](https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Writing-Tests-with-Intern#returning-a-promise) for more details.

Comment: This is the easiest solution and is correct, which I find silly emphasizing since it's also written by one of the authors of Intern. Worth mentioning that intern uses dojo promises internally, so you can utilize `dojo/promise/first` with a promisified setTimeout to create finer grained control over how long each parts of a particular tests take.